# Documentation and code for functions that require a backtick ` to access in function form

Tags: r, dplyr

For example, the math operators `+, -, *, /` are all defined as infix operators so that `1 + 3` can also be written as `` `+`(1, 3) ``. ([Further reading](http://www.programiz.com/r-programming/infix-operator)).

I know that you can sometimes get the documentation for these functions by using `` ?`+` `` or `` help(`+`) ``.

However, this is not working for the `distr` package, which defines the above mathematical operators on random variables which are class objects. E.g.

```
library(distr)
Norm() * Norm()
```

I have tried things like `` help(`distr::*`) `` and `` help(distr::`*`) ``. Interestingly if I try

```
library(dplyr)
help(`%>%`)
```

I get two links in the help window, one to the `dplyr` package and one to the `magrittr` package. I also do not know what syntax to use to access the help of `` dplyr::`%>%` `` directly.

Comment: `help(\`%>%\`, package=dplyr)` for your secondary question

Comment: or `?dplyr::\`%>%\``

Comment: thanks, it seems like there is no helpfile for these operators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
library(distr)
?operators
```

This may also be of interest:

```
?"Math-methods"
methods?Math # same
```

and also try this to browse the distr package `"-class"` help files, keyword `math` help files and keyword `arith` help files:

```
help.search("class", package = "distr")
help.search("math", fields = "keyword", package = "distr")
help.search("arith", fields = "keyword", package = "distr")
```

If you want to browse *all* the help files for the distr package:

```
help(package = "distr")
```

You can also browse the source at https://github.com/cran/distr or http://distr.r-forge.r-project.org or download it from its CRAN home page https://cran.r-project.org/package=distr .